# How to use javascript on backend of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to register a script with wordpress that will work on the backend.  I thought any script I registered in my functions.php file would work but it only shows in the front end. Anyone any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I found a post on wordpress stack exchange that helped me enormously, so here it is for anyone else with same problem:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/load-a-script-just-to-custom-post-type-in-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_head', 'myscriptinthe_admin_header' );
function myscriptinthe_admin_header(){
  echo "<script>alert( 'in the admin head!' )</script>";
}

add_action( 'admin_head', function(){ ?>    
<script> alert( 'in the admin head!' ) </script> 
<?php }); ?>
```

Comment: is there a way to include a javascript file though other than hardcoding it into the above function by echoing?

Comment: did do, I posted a comment to my question with a link to solution

Comment: You forgot a closure for the anonymous function `<?php }); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, sometimes we may need to add javascript to the footer of WordPress admin backend instead of in the head.

In this case, we will use the '**admin_footer**' hook instead of '**admin_head**'.